# Why Intellij marks the code with the yellow background

Tags: intellij-idea, yaml

I installed IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.3 (Community Edition) on my new Mac and have a weird issue with a file containing a YAML document. The code in the editor has a yellow background. It is only for files containing YAML documents. How to get rid of this?
[image]

Comment: If you hover over it with your mouse, to you get a tooltip?

Comment: no, no any tooltip.

Comment: Update. I disable highlight yaml schema   validation in the settings and it disappeared

Comment: Seems your YAML schema is not defined, or incorrect. attach the whole YAML file to check  that.

Comment: how do we disable this madness?

Answer (score 0):

This is how i solved the problem for myself. (I am using Jetbrains - WebStorm. a little different than intellij but very similar IDE). On Mac OS - Go to Settings > Editor >  Code Style > Inspections > (look for your yaml options) > uncheck "Validation by JSON Schema" > apply > ok

[Screenshot of IDE Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x34jB.png)